# Java application crashing down

Tags: java

I made a simple library management application in Java. When I run it and enter a title of a book for e.g. "Java : How To Program" it crashes. But if I just enter "Java" instead of "Java : How To Program", things work well.

What is wrong ? Please help.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainSystem {

static String fileName = null;
static Library lib = new Library();
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
static Boolean running = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (running) {
        System.out.println("\nEnter 0 for load a library."
                + "\nEnter 1 for save and quit"
                + "\nEnter 2 for list all books in library"
                + "\nEnter 3 for add book to library");

        int answer = in.nextInt();
        switch (answer) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Enter the file name to load");
            loadScript(in.next());
            break;

        case 1:
            saveAndQuit();
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(lib.toString());
            break;
        case 3:
            addBook();
            break;
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}

private static void addBook() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int isbn;
    String title, author;
    double price;

    System.out.println("\nEnter Title: ");
    title = in.next();

    System.out.println("\nEnter Author: ");
    author = in.next();

    System.out.println("\nEnter ISBN: ");
    isbn = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nEnter Price: ");
    price = in.nextDouble();

    Book b = new Book(isbn, title, author, price);
    lib.addBook(b);
}

private static void saveAndQuit() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
    fileName = in.next() + ".ser";
    running = false;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        out.writeObject(lib);
        fos.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void loadScript(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    File file = new File(name + ".ser");
    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            lib = (Library) in.readObject();
            fis.close();
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("\nThe file does not exist!");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: share the steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to read the spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29

Comment: Closing the file should be done in a `finally` block in case an exception occurs while reading the file. There is no need to retain the `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` comments from your IDE once you've put your own code in the methods. They are at best a distraction.

Comment: @Braj : Here is the source code - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1xrPqpkpLGSMWYxNWdWbVVBeDA/edit?pli=1 - get hold of it and try doing what I tried to do in the question.

Comment: I am asking about the steps. Are you adding a new book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading the next `String` when you want/need to read the complete line. Change this:

```
in.next();
```

By

```
in.nextLine();
```

When asking for data for your book:

```
private static void addBook() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int isbn;
    String title, author;
    double price;

    System.out.println("\nEnter Title: ");
    title = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\nEnter Author: ");
    author = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\nEnter ISBN: ");
    isbn = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nEnter Price: ");
    price = in.nextDouble();

    Book b = new Book(isbn, title, author, price);
    lib.addBook(b);
}
```

---

From comment:

> When I change in.next to in.nextLine, while running the program Enter Title and Enter Author` appear simultaneously; instead first Enter Title should appear and after giving a Title Enter Author should appear

Note that `nextLine` will consume every input until the `Scanner` finds a new break line input. This means that you have to add an additional `nextLine()` before reading the data for the books:

```
private static void addBook() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int isbn;
    String title, author;
    double price;
    in.nextLine(); //consume the data...

    System.out.println("\nEnter Title: ");
    title = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\nEnter Author: ");
    author = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\nEnter ISBN: ");
    isbn = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nEnter Price: ");
    price = in.nextDouble();

    Book b = new Book(isbn, title, author, price);
    lib.addBook(b);
}
```

More info:

[`Scanner.nextLine` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine)

Comment: That will still cause an issue as the `:` character is not valid in a path or filename on most systems.

Comment: @hexafraction that wasn't the intention of the post. Anyway, updated.

Comment: @hexafraction by the way, you could even write `file:name` and will be read by `Scanner#next`, there's no salvation for that.

Comment: When I change `in.next` to `in.nextLine`, while running the program `Enter Title and `Enter Author` appear simultaneously; instead first `Enter Title` should appear and after giving a Title `Enter Author` should appear.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : Can you please elaborate why did we use an additional `in.nextLine();` before reading the books ?

Comment: @LancePreston it is written in my answer: *Note that nextLine will consume every input until the `Scanner` finds a new break line input. This means that you have to add an additional `nextLine()` before reading the data for the books*. If you just read the `nextInt` and then try to read the `nextLine`, `nextInt` will read the `integer` input and `nextLine` will read everything until the break line input: everything between the integer input and the break line input.

Comment: @LancePreston don't forget to mark this post as the answer.